# Use Replace in Access SQL only when the first two characters of the string match my pattern

Tags: sql, ms-access, replace, ms-access-2010

I'm working with a database where names with apostophes in them (e.g. Irish or Scottish style names such as O’Doherty) are stored with a space instead of the apostophe (e.g. "O Doherty").

In my query, I want to return the names in their correct format (just in this SELECT query, rather than actually changing the data), so I've used:

```
 Replace([snametemp],"O ","O’")
```

This works in theory, but the problem I'm having is where there are matches for the pattern further along the string: e.g., "DO NOT USE" would be returned as "DO’ NOT USE".

How would I write a Replace statement that only checked the first two characters of a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be something like that in access

```
IIF(snametemp like "O *", Replace([snametemp],"O ","O’"), snametemp)
```

Comment: Perfect! I was wrongly assuming there was a setting in the Replace statement itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how can this syntax can be used in Access. This Question was originally posted under **`tsql`**

use case statement **`case...when...then...else...end`**

```
case when substring(snametemp,0,2) like "O’" then Replace([snametemp],"O ","O’") else snametemp end as snametemp
```